# Why the single copy live on a flat background in type D Weyl double copy？

Tags: spinors, double-copy

Showed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08183), the Weyl double copy relates exact solutions in general relativity to exact solutions in gauge theory, formulated in the spinorial language. The relation can be expressed as $\Psi_{ABCD}=\frac{1}{S}f_{(AB}f_{CD)}$, wher $\Psi_{ABCD}$ is Weyl tensor of the curve spacetime and $f_{AB}$ is Maxwell tensor of electromagnetic field living on Minkowski spacetime. Furthermore, $\Psi_{ABCD}=\Psi_2 \omicron_{(A} \omicron_B \iota_C \iota_{D)}$ and $f_{AB}=\phi_1 \omicron_{(A} \iota_{B)}$, which details showed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08183). According to the relation, the spinor bases ($\omicron_A$ and $\iota_A$) of LHS is as same as RHS. And the spinor bases is related to spacetime. So why the electromagnetic field live on a flat background rather than curve spacetime? Is this a coincidence?